# @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, firebase, geofire

I just built an angularjs app using geofire for location. It works perfectly in production but has issues when i deploy it to firebase. I believe the error should be from here

```
getLocations(radius: number, coords: Array<number>) {
    console.log(radius, coords)
    this.geoFire.query({
        center: coords,
        radius: radius
    })
    .on('key_entered', (userKey, location, distance) => {
        //we need to check this because this.hits the behavioursubject already cached previous result and geofire fetches again each time we go back to homepage
        const existAlready = this.hits.value.filter(h=>h.userKey === userKey)
        if(existAlready.length > 0){
            return
        }
        console.log(userKey)
        const u = this.userList.query.ref
                      .child(`/${userKey}`)
                      .on('value',s=>{
                        const {name, address} = s.val()
                        console.log(s.val())
                        let hit = {
                            location,
                            distance,
                            name,
                            address,
                            userKey
                        }

                        let currentHits = this.hits.value
                        currentHits.push(hit)
                        this.hits.next(currentHits)

                        this.eventService.sendMessage(Constants.EVENT_MESSAGES.LOADING, true)
                      })
    })
}
```

The above code is meant to fetch the locations around me as soon as the app loads. But instead i get this error

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user
>   callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

The error only comes in production

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the error with the following versions of libraries

```
npm uninstall firebase 
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install firebase@^4.11.0
npm install angularfire2@^5.0.0-rc.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this same error in production in my application as well. The only thing that seems to fix it is clearing my google cache, history, and cookies. It isn't a permanent fix in the slightest, but try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the solution but that worked for me. I think the real problem happens once you deploy a new build and not clear the cache.

So for me, eveytime i deploy, i have to clear the cache again.

interesting enough, this just happens in chrome. I tested it in Edge and i don't have to go through that.